# NodeJS Memory "Leak"?

Tags: node.js, memory, garbage-collection

I have written a nested looping simulation/algorithm using Node 8.9.4. It uses Promises and the promise-do-whilst library to implement the loops. On a computer with lots of RAM (32GB) its runs to completion without issue. Likewise,  on a Raspberry Pi 3B with 1GB of RAM, it takes significantly longer to execute, but does run to completion typing out at about 25-30% RAM utilization according to `top`.

Running on a Digital Ocean droplet wth 1GB of RAM, though, the RAM utilization grows rapidly, and eventually (pretty quickly) Node crashes with a bad allocation and dumps core.

My conclusion, then, is that the NodeJS runtime garbage collector isn't keeping up with the algorithm's temporary variable allocations when running on a faster but RAM-constrained computing environment. Question is what, if anything, can I do to help the garbage collector do its job better with respect to my algorithm?

Comment: You'll probably have to distill some simple code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I appreciate the comment that I should distill a simple example that reproduces the problem, that proved to be a bridge too far for me with this particular algorithm. I did find the difference in my environments that proved to be an adequate solution though. On the Digital Ocean droplet environment that was crashing, I was running Node 6.9.4 whereas in environments where it wasn't crashing I was running Node 8.9.4. Upgrading the droplet to Node 8.9.4 allowed it to complete without crashing. I guess Node 8.9.4 is better at garbage collection than Node 6.9.4 is my conclusion.